# Replacement for kicker.bundle in SystemConfiguration in OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, system-configuration

I'm trying to find the replacement for kicker.bundle that was found in /System/Library/SystemConfiguration in OS X pre 10.5 (Leopard). I can't seem to find any sort of official documentation on the matter. Does anyone know what the replacement is?

Thanks,
k.

Answer (score 3):

A group of system administrators created “crankd” as an alternative to kicker.xml. You can find it as part of PyMacAdmin at:

http://code.google.com/p/pymacadmin/

Crankd can “execute Python code or a shell script in response to many system events: network changes, filesystem activity, application launching, etc.”

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a fair amount of time looking for a solution. Doesn't seem like there is a direct replacement for kicker.bundle and kicker.xml to help launch a script when a network change occurs. That said I have found another solution that will probably do the trick:

http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/locationchanger/

k.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple source code to configd contains a kicker plugin,  I tried to compile it but it loads with some kind of circular reference error.  Maybe some slick programmer could figure it out.